# Investigating reason of garbage collection on Android Application startup

Tags: java, android, performance, garbage-collection

I am trying to debug the reason of garbage collection on Application Startup. But not able to find the reason for the same.

I tried using [TraceView](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview-walkthru.html), but the moment I go for method tracing the application has already started and not able to trace it.

Is there any other way to trace and identify the reason for garbage collection and tracing Application startup.

Thanks

Comment: Can you take a heap dump at the startup?